# Deploying a MS bot with ADO pipeline instead of az webapp deployent

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, botframework, ado

At the moment, I am using the az CLI to deploy my bot to Azure with the following command:

`az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group MY_RESOURCE_GROUP --name MY_RESOURCE_NAME --src MY_BOT_ZIP`

I'm trying to deploy the bot from an Azure DevOps pipeline. Here's what I tried:

```
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: AzureWebApp@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: MY_SUBSCRIPTION
    appType: webAppLinux
    appName: MY_RESOUCE_NAME
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

However, this resulted in a deployment failure with the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/bunyan'
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Kudu Sync failed
\n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh "/home/site/deployments/tools/deploy.sh"
Deployment Failed. deployer = VSTS_ZIP_DEPLOY deploymentPath = ZipDeploy. Extract zip.
##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: KuduStackTraceURL
##[error]KuduStackTraceURL https://...
##[error]Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
```

When I modified the `ArchiveFiles@2` task to set `includeRootFolder: true`, the deployment was successful, but the bot didn't run. I believe this might be due to an incorrect deployment structure caused by the extra folder.

Am I on the right track? Is there a better way to achieve this deployment?

Answer (score 1):

If you can deploy the app with Azure CLI successfully, please try to check if the zip file you are deploying in the pipeline is the same with the one you deployed with the Azure CLI.

You can add some steps to check what is in the zip file. Here is my sample yaml by adding the script to list the files in the folder `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` and publishing the zip file as pipeline artifact. Then we can see what is archived in the pipeline log and download the pipeline artifact manually to check the files.
[image]

```
    - script: ls $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
      inputs:
        targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        artifact: 'WebApp'
        publishLocation: 'pipeline'

    - task: AzureWebApp@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'MY_SUBSCRIPTION'
        appType: 'webApp'
        appName: 'MytestApp'
        package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        deploymentMethod: 'auto'
```

By the way, you can also use the Azure CLI task in the pipeline with your command instead of the `AzureWebApp@1` task.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'MY_SUBSCRIPTION'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: 'az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group MY_RESOURCE_GROUP --name MY_RESOURCE_NAME --src MY_BOT_ZIP'
```

Hope the above can help you solve the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, the pipeline shows '0 published' artifacts so I am unable to check the content of the artifact.

Comment: Have you added the `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` task in your yaml?